# Hover effect vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I got an interesting problem in my vuejs UI.

I am rendering this using `v-for` and I want to have a **hover** effect **ONLY** for a single *Topic*

[image: Hover]

but what happens is all of the items in the list gets the hover effect instead of just an individual topic.

[image]

How do I target or get that specific Topic in the list?

I use a method on `@mouseleave` and `@mouseover` to trigger a function. I can always pass the `:key` to the method but I don't know how to target use the **key** inside the function to apply CSS to that individual topic only. 
[image]

This happens because all of the items in the list depends on a single data source.

[image]

How do I apply class/style or CSS to that specific topic only?

Comment: Can you not just use CSS `:hover`? Eg, replace `.topic.hover` with `.topic:hover`

Comment: My god. that's basic css. I'm so stupid. My brain is so stuck deep into vue that I forgot basic css. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set and reset hovered subject id on `@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` as follows:

```
<div @mouseover = "hoverToggle(subject.id, 'mouseOver')"
     @mouseleave = "hoverToggle(subject.id, 'mouseLeave')">
```

Make changes in the function as follows:

```
hoverToggle = function(subjectId, action){
    switch(action){
        case 'mouseOver':
            this.hoveredSubjectId = subjectId;
        case 'mouseLeave':
            this.hoveredSubjectId = "";
    }
}
```

Add dynamic class for your `div` as follows:

```
<div class="(subject.id === hoveredSubjectId) ? 'hover':'no-hover'">
```

Comment: @Shu Pesmerga checkout this answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I understand this now. Using ternary operators to return the class or not. Totally forgot that feature.